# how to use box2d b2Distance function

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

i know b2Distance is used to compute two shape's distance,but how to use it? i don't know how to set the parameters of b2Distance(),e.g this is the structure of b2DistanceInput ,
public class b2DistanceInput

```
{
                public var proxyA:b2DistanceProxy;
                public var proxyB:b2DistanceProxy;
                public var transformA:b2Transform;
                public var transformB:b2Transform;
                public var useRadii:Boolean;
}
```

does anybody can tell me what's b2DistanceProxy?what's useRadii,if you can give me an example,it will help to a lot,thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just pass the 2 bodies position on `b2Distance` parameters:

```
float distance = b2Distance(body1->GetPosition(), body2->GetPosition());
```